# Clicking a button 3 times in a row to trigger a toast?

Tags: java, android

I was just wondering how to create a toast (or trigger something else to happen) when clicking on button 3 times in a row?

For example: I've created a coin flip so far and I want a toast to appear if the user manages to get 3 heads/tails in a row.

**This is my current code:**

```
        if (randomNumber == 1) {

        Log.i("Result", "Heads");

        greycoin.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000).rotationYBy(1800);
        redcoin.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(1000).rotationYBy(1800);

        view.animate()
                .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Heads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .start();

    } else {

        Log.i("Result", "Tails");

        greycoin.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(1000).rotationYBy(1800);
        redcoin.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000).rotationYBy(1800);

        view.animate()
                .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tails", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .start();

    }

}
```

I'm still incredibly new to Java and programming, so please pardon my poor programming vocabulary.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Think of it this way.  You need to keep track of how many times something has happened.  So there are three pieces: capturing the event, tracking it, and acting when the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the gesture instead:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    int numberOfTaps = 0;
    long lastTapTimeMs = 0;
    long touchDownMs = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchDownMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

                if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - touchDownMs) > ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()) {
                    //it was not a tap

                    numberOfTaps = 0;
                    lastTapTimeMs = 0;
                    break;
                }

                if (numberOfTaps > 0 
                        && (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapTimeMs) < ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout()) {
                    numberOfTaps += 1;
                } else {
                    numberOfTaps = 1;
                }

                lastTapTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (numberOfTaps == 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "triple click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //handle triple tap
                }

        return true;
    }
});
```